# ValidationAttribute Custom

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, data-annotations, validationattribute

I'm a little new in MVC and I'm needing to validate a field by checking where the field can not have the value Espécifico NotFound as an example, could someone give me a suggestion of how to do? I tried to elaborate a custom validation, but it does not return me the value that was filled in the field. Below is the verification code I tried.

```
 public sealed class ValidationOwner : ValidationAttribute
{
    protected override ValidationResult IsValid(object value, ValidationContext validationContext)
    {
        var entityOwner = validationContext.ObjectInstance as SegnalazioneModClientModel;

        if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace((string)value))
        {
            if ((string)value == "notfound")
                return new ValidationResult(Resources.Resource.OwnerInvalid);
            else
                return ValidationResult.Success;
        }
        else
            return new ValidationResult(Resources.Resource.OwnerInvalid);
    }
```

Thanks for the attention.

Comment: What do you mean *it does not return me the value that was filled in the field*? Are you saying your custom validation attribute is not returning an error or anything, or are you saying the model you are using this validation attribute is not getting an value (or not getting data bound)?

Comment: usually `value` is the value that we filled in the field. Check whether you're sending the right values.